# why xampp server genrating error on my local server?

Tags: php, apache, server, xampp

Xampp giving me error  how to slove this error

[image: Screen Shot Error]

Comment: from the looks of it, that's an old-a$$ pc. could be memory or cpu problem. check your cpu and ram performance while running your code.

Comment: xampp is 32 bit and ram of my pc is 32 GB . and i have check the PC their is no Problem with it. i am using Oracle data base with my PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error is solve by installing its services and on the left side its marked green tick after installing this problem is solved.

[image]